# pyautogui не импортируется в .exe файл Python

Tags: python, exe, pyautogui

Когда импортирую код в exe то всё работает он импортировался, но как только я запускаю exe файл появляется окно которое я сделал сам:

pg.alert("Добро Пожаловать!", "AutoBot", button="Запустить")

button = open("main.py")

Я нажимаю запустить и нечего не происходит, подскажите пожалуйста что надо сделать?